# .NET SQL server Cannot Select until I insert first

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, formatexception

I'm trying to get all rows from a table using a stored procedure for sqlserver. 
on .Net when i call the procedure i get a `System.FormatException`. But if i call the exact same code AFTER I insert anything to that table using another stored procedure, it works perfectly fine.

This is the SELECT stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_VAS_PRO]
(
   @i_operation                        CHAR(1),
   @i_option                           CHAR(1),

   @i_Id                               INT OUTPUT,

   @i_pName                            VARCHAR(MAX),
   @i_pDesc                            VARCHAR(MAX),
   @i_active                           INT
)
AS 
BEGIN
/*==========================================*/
/*           OPERACIONES DE CONSULTA        */
/*==========================================*/
   IF @i_operation = 'S' 
   BEGIN


      IF @i_option = 'A'
      BEGIN      
         SELECT    id
                  ,pName
                  ,pDesc
                  ,active
              FROM VAS_PROYECT
      END
  END
```

And this is the code that calls the procedure:

```
public Project()
        {
            db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("VasaroCore");

            command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_VAS_PRO");

            db.AddInParameter(command, "i_operation", DbType.String, "");
            db.AddInParameter(command, "i_option", DbType.String, "");

            db.AddParameter(command, "i_Id", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.InputOutput, "", DataRowVersion.Current, 32);
            db.SetParameterValue(command, "i_Id", null);
            db.AddInParameter(command, "i_pName", DbType.AnsiString, "");
            db.AddInParameter(command, "i_pDesc", DbType.AnsiString, "");
            db.AddInParameter(command, "i_active", DbType.Int32, "");
        }

 public List<Objects.Project> ListProjects()
        {
            List<Objects.Project> res = new List<Objects.Project>();

            Objects.Project item = null;

            db.SetParameterValue(command, "i_operation", 'S');
            db.SetParameterValue(command, "i_option", 'A');

            IDataReader dr = null;

            try
            {
                dr = db.ExecuteReader(command);


                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    item = ConstructProject(dr);
                    res.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "DataAccess Policy");

                if (rethrow)
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                if (dr != null)
                {
                    dr.Close();
                }
            }

            return res;
        }
```

As you can see, i'm not making any convertion, but the error says: "`Error converting the value of the String parameter to Int32.`".

Error StackTrace:

```
System.FormatException: Error al convertir el valor del parámetro de String a Int32. ---> System.FormatException: La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.
   en System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   en System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   en System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   en System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue()
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   en System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   en Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteReader(DbCommand command, CommandBehavior cmdBehavior)
   en Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteReader(DbCommand command)
   en Vasaro.Data.Access.Project.ListProjects() en C:\Users\CAMAYA\source\repos\vasaro\Vasaro.Data.Access\Project.cs:línea 93
```

Comment: maybe in your SP, these 2 parameters are not string?

Comment: What does `ConstructProject()` do?   I bet the conversion happens there.

Comment: It's curious that your procedure parameters are prefixed with `i_` but have character values. Please post the entire procedure code.

Comment: What is 'db'?  What is 'command'? Where is 'command' created?

Comment: Are you using a global connection, and not passing the connection to your procedures? That's not really good coding practice. And I would wager that the 'db' object is opened in the insert code, so it exists only after you perform an insert.

Comment: I add the declarations for command and db. And the entire stored procedure. @TabAlleman i get the error in `ExecuteReader(command);` so it does not get to call `ConstructProject();`

Comment: `when i call the procedure i get a System.FormatException` <= You need to include the details from the Exception. That is one of the reasons why Exceptions were created (to help you figure out why/where errors occur and more easily handle them). Include the full [StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) and the `Message`. Also include the line in your code where the Exception is thrown (if it is not obvious from the StackTrace).

Comment: @Igor edited. The line 93 is the `ExecuteReader(command);` line

Comment: Read the error message, there is an error converting the result to an int. Could be an input or output but the string is either not numeric **or** the value of the thing being converted is `null` or `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Try changing   db.AddParameter(command, "i_Id", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.InputOutput, "", DataRowVersion.Current, 32);  to Output instead of input/output.  the next line assigns null to this parameter, which is specified as Int in the sproc.  It might be trying to assign it.

Comment: Slight detour...https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the error is below line -

```
db.AddInParameter(command, "i_active", DbType.Int32, "");
```

You are passing empty string to `Int32` parameter which will fail.

Also you should consider using `DBNull.value` instead of `null` while assigning values to parameters.

```
db.SetParameterValue(command, "i_Id", DBNull.Value);
db.AddInParameter(command, "i_active", DbType.Int32, DBNull.Value);
```